# Error in executing SQL scripts via powershell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I am getting below error while executing a sample SQL script after installing SQL Server 2019 in an Azure VM via automation.

Script:

```
   `$serverName = "b2i911clp-a\IT911B2I01"
$databaseName = "test"
$username = "sa"
$password = "******"

# Create a new SqlConnection object
$connectionString = "Server=$serverName;Database=$databaseName;User ID=$username;Password=$password;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)

$connection.Open()

$query = @"
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    EmployeeID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    LastName VARCHAR(50),
    Email VARCHAR(100),
    Department VARCHAR(50),
    Salary DECIMAL(10, 2)
);
"@

Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $serverName -Database $databaseName -Username $username -Password $password -Query $query
```

`

The error which concerns me more is:

> provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The
> certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.

I have disabled encryption and set network protocol flag to NO in SQL Server network configuration.

Any suggestions?

The script should execute smoothly.

Comment: Please don't use images for code, data or errors - use formatted text.

Comment: Show the actual code in the question too. Now it's being cut off, so it's hard to see what's going on on line whatever where the error is being invoked.

Comment: set TrustServerCertificate=True in ConnectionString

Comment: Yes, but ideally you would configure SQL Server with a proper certificate. Using `TrustServerCertificate` is effectively no security at all. Unclear why you are opening a separate connection object (because `Invoke-SqlCmd` doesn't use it), if you are going to go to that bother might as well go the whole way and just use `SqlCommand` also.